# Exclude all the jar's from webapp/WEB-INF/lib

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have the third party jar's in my WEB project placed at `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/`

I have mentioned the dependency for all the **required** JAR's in the **pom.xml**.
Now, Since the dependencies are defined in POM, the JAR's will be automatically packed in the `lib` folder.

- I want to exclude all the JAR's in the `lib`.
- The Dependency JAR's should be packaged inside the lib while building the WAR

**I CANT DELETE THE `LIB` FROM WEB-INF BECAUSE ITS USED IN LOCAL DEVELOPMENT**

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>META-INF/context.xml</packagingExcludes>
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: there is no reason to have this `lib` dir for `local development` Maven caches everything locally and Eclipse, Idea and Netbeans all know how to pull dependencies from there. If you are developing in a Tomcat `webapps` directory, then that is terrible practice. Maven can build and deploy a `war` file seamlessly to all the popular J2EE containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<configuration>
    <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</warSourceExcludes>
    ....
</configuration>
```

However, I do agree with Jarrod that it is bad practice to store your jars in `WEB-INF/lib` 'manually'.  I used this before to avoid that jars coming as a dependency got packaged to be able to repackage it afterwards.

Comment: Can you try omitting some of the other configuration details?  Just for testing?  Maybe there's some kind of a conflict, if you use that setting alone, it does work.

Answer (score 7):

It should be "packagingExcludes" instead of "warSourceExcludes":

```
<configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
    ....
</configuration>
```

From http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html :

> In version 2.1-alpha-1, this was incorrectly named warSourceExcludes

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't have anything in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory to begin with. If you are using Eclipse, you can tell it to build its project from the `pom.xml` and it will know to look in `~/.m2/repository` for dependencies, Intellij IDEA does this as well. Putting dependencies in `WEB-INF/lib` kind of defeats the purpose of using Maven for dependency management. What happens when the dependencies in the `pom.xml` get out of sync version wise with those in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not right to have anything in `WEB-INF/lib`, but I am building a legacy project here and it's very difficult to remove the libraries from this location (Local development will be affected)

Comment: first step in dealing with a legacy build system is to **pay the technical debt** and fix it to build in a single step, you will benefit immediately and everyone coming after you will benefit as well, saving money and time for the company.